# How to replace 0 values in a numpy array to other values based on column range?

Tags: python, numpy

I have a dataset in the following format:

`[[ 226      600   3.33    915.     92.6    98.6 ]
  [ 217      700   3.34    640.    93.7    98.5 ]
  [ 213      900   3.35    662.    88.8    96.  ]
  ...
  [ 108      600    2.31   291.     64.     70.4 ]
  [ 125      800    3.36   1094.    65.5    84.1 ]
  [ 109      400    2.44   941.     52.3    68.7 ]]`

Each column is a separate criteria that has its own value range. How can I impute values that are `0` to a value that is more than zero based on its column range? In other words the worst minimal value other than 0.

I have written the following code but it can only either change the `0` to the minimal value in the column (which is of course `0`) or `max`. The `max` varies by column. Thanks for your help!

```
# Impute 0 values -- give them the worst value for that column

I, J = np.nonzero(scores == 0)
scores[I,J] = scores.min(axis=0)[J] # can only do min or max
```

Comment: more than 0 but less than max, so in other words the worst value in a column other than 0. Sorry for the confusion

Comment: Yes, my bad. I've edited

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way would be to use a [`masked array`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/maskedarray.html) to find the minimum value along the columns masking those that are `<=0`. And replace the `0s` in the array with the corresponding minimum using [`np.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
min_gt0 = np.ma.array(r, mask=r<=0).min(0)
np.where(r == 0, min_gt0, r)
```

---

Here's an example:

```
r = np.random.randint(0,5,(5,5))

print(r)
array([[2, 1, 3, 0, 4],
       [0, 4, 4, 2, 2],
       [4, 0, 0, 0, 1],
       [1, 2, 2, 2, 2],
       [2, 0, 4, 4, 2]])

min_gt0 = np.ma.array(r, mask=r<=0).min(0)
np.where(r == 0, min_gt0, r)

array([[2, 1, 3, 2, 4],
       [1, 4, 4, 2, 2],
       [4, 1, 2, 2, 1],
       [1, 2, 2, 2, 2],
       [2, 1, 4, 4, 2]])
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution. I was having issues but then realised I need to declare a variable for `np.where...`

Comment: Yes you have to assign it to a variable. You're welcome @asleniovas :)

Answer (score 1):

I think the [numpy.ma.masked_equal](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ma.masked_equal.html) function is what you need.

consider an array:

```
a = np.array([4, 3, 8, 0, 5])
m = np.ma.masked_equal(a, 0) # mask = [0, 0, 0, 1, 0]
```

now you can call `m.min()` and the value is the second smallest value in the column.

```
m.min() # 3
```